# android emulator is not invoking for ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, android-sdk-2.3

when I'm using the command

> ionic cordova run android

it is showing the message like 
Android Studio project detected

> ANDROID_HOME=D:\SDK
>       JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
>       studio
>       (node:1072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an in
>       stalled version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>       or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
>       in your path, or install Android Studio
>           at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\andr
>       oid\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:150:18)
>           at StudioBuilder.prepEnv (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\l
>       ib\builders\StudioBuilder.js:216:23)
>           at Api.module.exports.run (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\
>       lib\build.js:154:20)
>           at D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:342:43
>           at _fulfilled (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules
>       \q\q.js:854:54)
>           at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordo
>       va\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
>           at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android
>       \cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
>           at D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:
>       44
>           at runSingle (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\
>       q\q.js:137:13)
>           at flush (D:\ionic apps\dummyapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.
>       js:125:13)
>       (node:1072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>       error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
>       block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
>        id: 1)
>       (node:1072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
>       cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>        Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> ```
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.
>      Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
>
> [16:09:09]  lint finished in 2.80 s
>
> D:\ionic apps\dummyapp>
> ```
>
> and android emulator in not popping up.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have android studio installed and path is set correctly.

Comment: I've installed only android SDK, not the android studio.

Comment: Why would you need Android Studio for this? Just because Google says you have to install it? You most certainly don't need that, keep using the standalone Android SDK.

Comment: well maybe because latest versions of cordova require android studio install and don't work anymore with the standalone sdk?